# k8s node get services for a namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, certificate

I need to get the list of k8s services for some namespace, I need to run it in my local machine which is connected to k8s cluster . e.g. if I run `kubectl get ns` on **my machine(macbook)** I **get the list** for namespaces and the same for services using `kubectl get svc -n abc`

My kubeconfig is defined under my mac `/Users/i453335/.kube/config` file

When I try to run the following code, I got error

`Error: unable to get issuer certificate`  (not sure how to provide it and from where) or maybe I need to to use `loadFromDefault` differently ...

Any idea how I could make it work?

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespacedService('abc').then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

This is the lib I use:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript

Comment: Is kubeconfig present in filename config or file name is different. By default as shown in code it will check for filename config in the path you specified

Comment: @yogeshkunjir - the file is under `/Users/i453335/.kube/config` , any idea if I can maybe control it with the lib? do you think I miss something?

Comment: Which kubernetes you trying to connect to remote one? Can you get pod using kubectl get pod?

Comment: @yogeshkunjir - yes sure Im able to access pods ns srv etc from my mac terminal using the kubeconfig I've put in `/Users/i453335/.kube/config`

Comment: Bit strange. Kubernetes use self sign certificate and it will create it's own CA which sign the certificate. Now in your case it is failing at ssl handshake. Mean it get kubeapi certificate but it can't complete chain because it does not have root CA installed. Hence unable to get issuers cert. Final one can you install that ca.cert in mac?